# How can I pass a command line variable as an argument to RobotFramework Listener?

Tags: robotframework

Here's what I am trying to do:

I am trying to write a robotframework listener and I need to pass some arguments to it.

```
robot --listener /path/to/MyListener.py -v VARIABLE_NAME1:VARIABLE_VALUE1 -v VARIABLE_NAME2:VARIABLE_VALUE2 -d Results /path/to/Test.robot
```

I would like to pass VARIABLE_NAME1 and VARIABLE_NAME2 etc to MyListener.py as arguments as opposed to writing them as follows:

```
robot --listener /path/to/MyListener.py;VARIABLE_VALUE1:VARIABLE_VALUE2 -d Results /path/to/Test.robot
```

Can this be done? Appreciate any help/guidance in advance.

Comment: I am going to take inspiration from the work done on the reportportal code by the team: 
https://github.com/reportportal/agent-Python-RobotFramework/blob/master/robotframework_reportportal/variables.py

I dont fully understand the code yet, but I think it has what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to my question:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn, RobotNotRunningError
from robot.api import logger

    class SampleListener:
        ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2
    
        def __init__(self):
            self._variables = None
    
        def get_all_variables(self):
            """
            Gets all the RobotFramework Command Line variables as a dictionary
            Returns: Dictionary of command line variables
            """
            self._variables = dict(BuiltIn().get_variables())
            return self._variables
```

From this point forward you can access the variable from **self._variables**